# Combining two reference variables

Tags: php

Is it somehow possible to "glue" two reference variables?

For example

```
$more = &$first.':'.&$second;
```

Using this, i receive a **syntax error**, an unexpected **&**.

Full code

```
$numOf = isset($_GET['numof']) ? $_GET['numof'] : 'x';

if($numOf == 1) {

$more = &$first;

} else if($numOf == 2) {

$more = &$first.':'.&$second;

} else {

$more = '';

}

$results = array(); // array with results from database

foreach($results as $res) {

$first = $res[0];
$second = $res[1];

echo $more.$res[3];

}
```

Comment: Did you try to use brackets?

Comment: @Sakezzz not working

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by concatenating the references? In php these are not like pointers in C. They are symbol table aliases. You can't do arithmetic with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Closure to achieve what you want. Indeed, you need PHP 7(Maybe 5.6, can't tell as I can't test) in order to achieve desired result. Here's an example:

```
<?php
$first = "a";
$second = "b";
$more = function(){ global $first,$second; return $first.$second; };

echo $more()."<br>"; // This will output ab
$first = "b";
echo $more(); // This will output bb
```

Comment: although, personally i'd guess a `function() use(&$first, &$second)` would be better than using globals, which *could* have unintended side effects.

Comment: Yes, nice point. Didn't have a chance to test it under PHP 5.6, so didn't want to suggest a probably-not-working answer.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is the following :

```
$ar = array(&$first, &$second);
$more = implode(":", $ar);
```

Comment: It is a viable option, but watch out because every action applied to such array will be applied to referenced variables too.

Answer (score 0):

not directly, at least not that i know of.
what you *could* do is create a class with a method that automatically combines the values. if you only want string output, you can use the magic method __tostring, so you can use the class directly:

```
class combiner
{
    private $a;
    private $b;
    public function __construct(&$a, &$b)
    {
        $this->a = &$a;
        $this->b = &$b;
    }
    public function __tostring() {
        return $this->a.":".$this->b;
    }
}

$ta = "A";
$tb = "B";
$combined = new combiner($ta, $tb);
echo $combined; //A:B
$ta = "C";
echo $combined; //C:B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your required result by:

```
<?php

function more($first, $second){
    if(!empty($_GET['numof'])){
        if($_GET['numof']==1)
            return $first;
        elseif($_GET['numof']==2)
            return $first.':'.$second
    }
    return '';
}

$results = array(); // array with results from database

foreach($results as $res) {
    $first = $res[0];
    $second = $res[1];
    echo more($first, $second).$res[3];
}
```